# iOS How to convert CGContextShowTextAtPoint to CTLineDraw when using a Transform?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-text

I have the following code:

```
CGContextSetFillColor(gr->layer_context, fg->rgba);
CGContextSelectFont(gr->layer_context, font->name, font->size/16.0, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(gr->layer_context, kCGTextFill);
CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformMake(dx/65536.0, dy/65536.0, dy/65536.0, -dx/65536.0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(gr->layer_context, xform);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(gr->layer_context, p->x, p->y, outb, strlen(outb));
```

As I need to display unicode characters as well, I want to convert it to use CTLineDraw instead.

This is the new code:

```
CGContextRef context = gr->layer_context;
CGContextSaveGState(context);

strcpy(outb, inp);

CFStringRef mytext = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, outb, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

if((dx!=0 && dx!=65536) || (dy !=0 && dy!=65536)) {
    dbg(lvl_error, "TEXT: %s  dx: %i  dy: %i", text, dx, dy);
}

// Create attributes
CFStringRef font_name = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, font->name, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CTFontRef font1 = CTFontCreateWithName(font_name, font->size/16.0, NULL);
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), fg->rgba);
CFStringRef keys[] = { kCTFontAttributeName, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName };
CFTypeRef values[] = { font1, color };
CFDictionaryRef font_attributes = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)&keys, (const void **)&values, 2, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFRelease(font_name);
CFRelease(font1);


CFAttributedStringRef attr_string = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, mytext, font_attributes);

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);

CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformMake(dx/65536.0, dy/65536.0, dy/65536.0, -dx/65536.0, p->x, p->y);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, xform);
CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attr_string);

CTLineDraw(line, context);

CFRelease(line);
CFRelease(attr_string);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

The problem is, that the transformation doesn't apply like when using CoreGraphics.
Horizontal text shows fine at the desired position. Rotated text is displayed weird. See screenshots.

OK with CG:

[image]

Weird with CoreText:

[image]